# RemoteFunction inside jQDateRangeSlider's UserValuesChanged Event

Tags: jquery-ui, grails, jquery-plugins, parameters

I have one drop-down and a jQDateRangeSlider(a jQuery widget) in index.gsp of my Grails app.I am posting the value selected in the dropdown and the range selected over the slider to a query in my controller using remoteFunction.I want these three values(2 values from the slider and one value from the drop-down) to be posted to the controller when either of the following events occur:

1. Drop-down changes
2. Values over the slider change

The remoteFunction works fine from the onChange of the drop-down but when I replicate the remoteFunction inside the UserValuesChanged block of the slider, it throws an  error.This is how my code looks like:

**Controller**

```
class PgtypController {



    def ajaxGetMv = {

        def pgtyp = Pgtyp.executeQuery("select p.date_hour ,p.visits, p.mv, p.browser,p.pagetype,p.platform,p.device,p.time_period from Pgtyp p where p.mv = ? and p.date_hour >= ? and p.date_hour <= ? order by col_0_0_ asc ",[ params.mv ] + params.list( 'date_hour' ))

        render pgtyp as JSON
    }

     def dataSource


        def datejson = {
        def sql = new Sql(dataSource)
        def rows = sql.rows("select min(date_hour) as a , max(date_hour) as b from pgtyp")
        sql.close()
        render rows as JSON
    }

     def index() { 

}
```

**GSP**

```
<form>
<g:select from="['AFFILIATES', 'CSE','DISPLAYADS','EMAIL','MOBILEWEB','OTHERS','ORGANIC','SEO', 'SEM']" name="mv" id = "mv" 
           onchange="${remoteFunction(
           controller:'Pgtyp', 
           action:'ajaxGetMv', 
           params:'\'mv=\' + escape(this.value)+\'&date_hour=\'+ z+\'&date_hour=\'+ b',
           //params:'\'mv=\'+this.value',
           onSuccess: 'printpgtyp(data)')}"
></g:select> 

</form>
<script>
dataFile = "http://localhost:8080/marchmock2/Pgtyp/datejson";

        d3.json(dataFile, function(error,data) {
        if (data) 
                dataset = data;
                var min = dataset[0].a;
                var min2 = new Date(min);
                var max = dataset[dataset.length - 1].b;
                var max2 = new Date(max);
                function addZero(val) {
            if (val < 10) {
                return "0" + val;
            }   
            return val;
            }
                var s = $j("#slider").dateRangeSlider({

            bounds: {
                "min": min2,
                "max": max2
            },
            range: {
                min: {
                    hours: 1
                }
            },
            formatter:function(val){
                var m = moment(val);
                return m.format("DD/MM/YYYY HH:00:00 ");
            },
             defaultValues:{
                min: min2,
                max: max2
            }
        });
                x = (s.dateRangeSlider("values").min);
        x.setMinutes(0);
        x.setSeconds(0);
                z = x.getFullYear()+'-'+(x.getMonth()+1)+ '-'+x.getDate()+' '+x.getHours()+':'+'00'+':'+'00' ;
                var y = (s.dateRangeSlider("values").max);
        y.setMinutes(0);
        y.setSeconds(0);
                b = y.getFullYear()+'-'+(y.getMonth()+1)+ '-'+y.getDate()+' '+y.getHours()+':'+'00'+':'+'00' ;
         $j('#slider').on("userValuesChanged",function (e, data) {
                       var x = datavalues.min;
                       x.setMinutes(0);
                       x.setSeconds(0);
                       z = x.getFullYear()+'-'+(x.getMonth()+1)+ '-'+x.getDate()+' '+x.getHours()+':'+'00'+':'+'00' ;
                        var last = data.values.max;
                        last.setMinutes(0);
                        last.setSeconds(0);
                       b = last.getFullYear()+'-'+(last.getMonth()+1)+ '-'+last.getDate()+' '+last.getHours()+':'+'00'+':'+'00' ;
                        ${remoteFunction(
                            controller:'Pgtyp', 
                            action:'ajaxGetMv', 
                            params:'\'mv=\' +$(\'mv\').value+\'&date_hour=\'+ z+\'&date_hour=\'+ b',
                            onSuccess: 'printpgtyp(data)')}


             })
        });
function printpgtyp(data)
{
console.log(data)
console.log(data.length)
}//end of printpgtyp
</script>
```

This however gives an error like this:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token &
```

Can anyone tell me where exactly am I going wrong? If the code is working fine inside onChange of select tag then why am I getting this error inside UserValuesChanged of the slider?

Comment: I think you may try additionally escape `&` in `params:'\'mv=\' +$(\'mv\').value+\'&date_hour=\'+ z+\'&date_hour=\'+ b'` line